# How to show/Hide when hover in Cycle2 caption

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have cycle2 plugin html:

```
<div class="cycle-box">
    <div class="cycle-slideshow" 
        data-cycle-fx="shuffle" 
        data-cycle-shuffle-right="0" 
        data-cycle-shuffle-top="-75" 
        data-cycle-speed="1000" 
        data-cycle-timeout="5000" 
        data-cycle-prev=".cycle-prev" 
        data-cycle-next=".cycle-next"
    >
        <div class="cycle-overlay"></div>

        <img src="neighbors-2014_48961397118651.jpg" data-cycle-title="Title 1" data-cycle-desc="Sonnenberg Gardens">
        <img src="doraemon-2014-nobita-and-the-haunts-of-evil_79831403058958.jpg" data-cycle-title="Title 2" data-cycle-desc="Muir Woods National Monument">
        <img src="maleficent-2014_13821402289461.jpg" data-cycle-title="Title 3" data-cycle-desc="San Franscisco Bay">
        <img src="blended-2014_83551399536938.jpg" data-cycle-title="Title 4" data-cycle-desc="Adirondack State Park">
    </div>
    <div class="cycle-prev"></div>
    <div class="cycle-next"></div>
</div>
```

and jQuery:

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').hover(function () {
    $(this).parent().find('.cycle-overlay').fadeIn();
},
function () {
     $('.cycle-overlay').hide();
});
```

i want when cycle2 start caption hide and show when hover. thankyou!

Comment: use $(this).find('.cycle-overlay').fadeIn();

Answer (score 1):

Just tried and i got your code working fine..

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pradeeppansari/bWTwL/1215/)

If you need any thing then let me know.. i will help you..

```
$('.cycle-slideshow').hover(function () {

   $(this).parent().find('.cycle-overlay').fadeIn();
},
function () {
   $('.cycle-overlay').hide();
});
```

Comment: You actually didn't mention the most important thing: that whole code should be wrapped with `document.ready` (or at least with `window.load` like in your fiddle).

Comment: If you seen left side in fiddle you got what i am using..BTW its wrapped with document.ready..

Comment: In updated fiddle you wrapped with `document.ready`, yes. But you did not mention it in your answer, just saying "your code works fine", which is incorrect, because you modified (add `document.ready`) code to make it works.

Comment: thankyou Pradeep Pansari,

it no working for me you can see demo :

http://jsfiddle.net/cnttlc/zua9g0ky/